# Preventing minipage from creating a blank page

Tags: minipage

So I've got a document that is leading off with a minipage. From what I understand, the minipage environment tries to fit the box it creates on the current page, and if it is unable to do so, it moves itself to the top of the next page. The document that I have is currently doing that, because the minipage is slightly larger than the page itself. As such, it moves itself to the next page, despite there being nothing before it on the page. Is there a way to get it to not flee away like this?

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{5 in}
\lipsum[10-25]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Using this generates a two page pdf. The first is blank, the second contains the lorem ipsum text flowing longer than the page itself. If you change the amount of text used so that it fits on one page, then it magically doesn't create the blank page either.

Comment: your description of minipage is rather misleading. minipage has no positioning logic at all, it just makes a box the size of its contents, that box is then positioned the same way as a big letter, it may be on the same line or same page as preceding text according to the normal line and page breaking that tex does, the line and page breaker has no information that it was a minipage

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess. I think my question is that, when LaTeX senses a box larger than what can fit on the page, it moves it to the next page and puts it at the top of that page. Why is it not just staying on the first page, given that there is nothing else on the page?

Comment: it's just a more or less accidental fallout from an error condition, basically by the time it knows the box is overfull it _doesn't_ know that there is nothing else on the page (it doesn't know there is a single box bigger than the page, it only knows the total page content is too big)  and anyway it doesn't do anything about it.  Essentially it's a user error (although only reported as a warning) and in all cases after a user error the log file is far more important than the typeset output. The intention is that the source is fixed, not that the output is great.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `\smash` to tell LaTeX to ignore the height of the box, and then `\clearpage` to manually insert a page break, as per Werner's answer.  However most of the time you cannot simply wrap a `\smash` around the `minipage` environment, because it will typically contain paragraph breaks and `\smash` does not allow these in its argument.  The solution is to use the `lrbox` environment to save the page into a box and then `\smash` that.  We can package this up into a new environment, which I've called `smashminipage`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox\thesmashminipage
\newenvironment{smashminipage}
  {\begin{lrbox}{\thesmashminipage}\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}}
  {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}\smash{\usebox{\thesmashminipage}}\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\begin{smashminipage}
\lipsum[10-17]

\lipsum[18-25]
\end{smashminipage}

Page 2 content
\end{document}
```

For a slightly more robust version of this `smashminipage` environment that will work if your page with a `multicols`, `tikzpicture` or title in a much larger font, you'll need to add a `\null` at the start of the `minipage`, e.g.

```latex
\newenvironment{smashminipage}
  {\begin{lrbox}{\thesmashminipage}\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
   \null\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
  {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}\smash{\usebox{\thesmashminipage}}\clearpage}
```

I admit I don't really understand why this is needed, which is why I haven't added that to my initial answer.

Comment: The robust version is what worked for me. Thanks a lot for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fact that you want to force the content to remain on the current page, yet it is *just* too tall to fit, you can `\smash` it (removing any vertical height) and then force a jump to the following page (if needed for additional content):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin = 0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\smash{% Your over-sized minipage...
  \begin{minipage}[t]{5in}
    \lipsum[10-25]
  \end{minipage}%
}

\clearpage

abc % Page 2 content

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works fine for this toy example, but rarely in practice because a `minipage` that occupies the whole of a page will frequently have several paragraphs.  Try replacing `\lipsum[10-25]` with `\lipsum[10-24]\par\lipsum[25]` (or with a blank line in place of `\par`).  You'll be told "`Paragraph ended before \makesm@sh was complete.`"  The problem is that plain TeX does not define `\makesm@sh` (the main implementation of `\smash`) using `\long\def`.